# Joomla: Extract javascript documentReady callback functions on AJAX success

Tags: php, jquery, joomla2.5, history.js

I'm building a plugin for Joomla that ajaxifies the front-end.  I've been using a script from balupton's [balupton's history js page](https://gist.github.com/854622), and it works fine, except any javascript using the `.ready()` function will not execute, as the DOM has already been loaded.

What I would like to do is somehow search the scripts being requested, and then strip out the functions that use `ready()`, and then execute them.

In the script, we already grab all the scripts referenced in each html file, and we have access to the text inside each js file:

```
// Add the scripts
                    $scripts.each(function(){
                        var $script = $(this), scriptText = $script.text(), scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
                        scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptText));
                        contentNode.appendChild(scriptNode);
                    });
```

I am considering doing a simple string replace, but then again, I'm not sure if there's a better way of going about doing this, as it will of course require regex due to the possibilities of varying callback functions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that changing the JS is the correct way. Have you tried simply firing the ready function manually?

```
jQuery.ready();
```